# How to refresh QAbstractSpinBox?

Tags: qt, qt4

I need QSpinBox for unsigned int. Therefore I have wrote simple class:

```
class UnsignedSpinBox : public QAbstractSpinBox {
private:
  uint32_t value = 0;
  uint32_t minimum = 0;
  uint32_t maximum = 100;
private:
  void stepBy(int steps) {
    if (steps < 0 && (uint32_t)(-1 * steps) > value - minimum)
      value = minimum;
    else if (steps > 0 && maximum - value < (uint32_t)steps)
      value = maximum;
    else
      value += steps;
    lineEdit()->setText(QString::number(value));
  }
  StepEnabled stepEnabled() const {
    if (value < maximum && value > minimum)
      return QAbstractSpinBox::StepUpEnabled | QAbstractSpinBox::StepDownEnabled;
    else if (value < maximum)
      return QAbstractSpinBox::StepUpEnabled;
    else if (value > minimum)
      return QAbstractSpinBox::StepDownEnabled;
    else
      return QAbstractSpinBox::StepNone;
  }
  QValidator::State validate(QString &input, int &) const {
    if (input.isEmpty())
      return QValidator::Intermediate;
    bool ok = false;
    uint32_t validateValue = input.toUInt(&ok);
    if (!ok || validateValue > maximum || validateValue < minimum)
      return QValidator::Invalid;
    else
      return QValidator::Acceptable;
  }

public:
  UnsignedSpinBox(QWidget* parent = 0) : QAbstractSpinBox(parent) {
    lineEdit()->setText(QString::number(value));
  }
  virtual ~UnsignedSpinBox() { }
};
```

In gerenal it works fine but it has one shortcoming. Step buttons are refreshed only after mouse moving (althouth function `stepEnabled` is called every second). As a result if I hold Page Up, my spin box gets maximum value and these step buttons don't change their state until I move my mouse. Or if value is 0, one pressing of Page Up or up arrow key on a keyboard changes value and text, but doesn't change buttons' state (down button is still disabled). Moreover, when value == maximum both buttons are disabled although function `stepEnabled` returnes QAbstractSpinBox::StepDownEnabled (I've checked it). What am I doing wrong? How can I enforce QAbstractSpinBox to draw these buttons correctly?

P.S. I use Debian. But I don't think it does matter since QSpinBox works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Qt on your platform is either too old or otherwise broken. It works fine on OS X, on both Qt 4.8.5 and Qt 5.2.0.

There are two other solutions:

1. If you don't care about full range of unsigned integer, simply use `QSpinBox` and set non-negative minimum and maximum. That's all. On platforms with 32 bit int, maximum `int` value is 2^31-1, that's about half of the maximum `uint` value of 2^32-1.
2. You can use `QDoubleSpinBox`. On sane platforms you care about, double has more than 32 bits of mantissa, so you can convert it to a `quint32` without loss of precision.

   If you want to be sure, just add `static_assert(sizeof(double)>4)` anywhere in your code.

   If one worries about performance, then it really doesn't matter. The calculations are performed at the rate of user input events: that's a couple dozen double operations per second. It doesn't matter.

Comment: I have tried this class on my Windows 7 Professional... These buttons don't become disabled at all (it seems that there is no this feature on Windows when using Qt). I didn't want using QDoubleSpinBox because double calculations is slower than integer...

On Linux and Windows I use Qt 5.2.0 and Qt Creator 3.0.0. But pro file contains the line `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets`

Comment: @user2717575: c++11 is irrelevant here. The *style you're using on Windows* may not make it obvious *visually* that the buttons are disabled. They are disabled nonetheless.

Comment: "c++11 is irrelevant here" I use non-static data members initializers in my class. They are available only with c++11. That's why I asked about c++11. OK. I will use QDoubleSpinBox, although it's pretty interesting what's wrong with my class.

Comment: @user2717575 How do you check that the buttons are not disabled? Don't tell me how they look, tell me how they act.

Comment: They are disabled. I meant that nothing changed visually (on Windows). And by words 'it seems that there is no this feature on Windows' I meant exactly visual effects. But on Linux they could seem to be disabled visually but I can press them and get correct result. So, I have visual issues with my class on Linux, although QSpinBox and QDoubleSpinBox works correctly (visually). Maybe it does matter, I insert this control in QTreeWidget column. But QSpinBox and QDoubleSpinBox, being inserted in this column, works fine.